# How to get remote state file for my latest Terraform (Enterprise) run?

Tags: api, hashicorp-vault

I want to get the latest run for my workspace and grab its Terraform state file. We are using Terraform Enterprise.

I did the below and I got get the payload:

```
https://ptfe-dev.company.com.au/api/v2/organizations/organization-name/workspaces/workspace1
```

I get output but information of the workspace id etc, but that is what not what I want.

With the above output, I get workspace id and I ran the query below:

```
https://ptfe-dev.companyname.com.au/api/v2/organizations/organization-name/workspaces/workspace1/current-state-version
```

However, the above query returns:

> Sorry, the page `/api/v2/organizations/rganization-name/workspaces/workspace1/states/sv-DKBZ2AFoV5mwY4kP` could not be found.
>
> This error could mean one of two things:
>
> - The resource doesn't exist
> - The resource exists, but you do not have permission to access it
>
> If someone has linked you to this resource, ensure that they have given you proper permissions to access it.

I can, however, access the same resource (workspace1) state file via TFE UI.

Can anyone please advise me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: As a debugging experiment, you could also attempt to access it via the TFE provider.

Comment: My apologies but how? Any documentation which can guide me? Thanks for the edit

Comment: I don't want to access it via TFE UI but on the command line. Just to clarify if I did not do it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the payload from the first API call, you'll get the reference to the endpoint to get the state.
`<tfe_host>/api/v2/workspaces/<workspace_id>/current-state-version`

To include outputs, add `include=putputs` parameter like this:
`<tfe_host>/api/v2/workspaces/<workspace_id>/current-state-version?include=outputs`

You only need the organizations to get the workspace itself. When you get the state, you're referencing the workspace ID directly and don't need to include the organization.